# Execute n lines of shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Is there a way to execute only a specified number of lines from a shell script? I will try copying them with head and putting them on a separate .sh, but I wonder if there's a shortcut...

Comment: Why do you ask? Can't you just use `bash -vx` to understand what the script is doing?

Comment: I have a 20 line script, and sometimes I want to execute only the first 2 lines & sometimes the whole thing.

Comment: Then make another script with only the two first lines.

Comment: Create a shell library. If those 2 lines do something useful, give them their own name.  It will improve your code.

Comment: I can, but I was hoping there would be a more flexible solution.

Comment: Running the first N lines is not a flexible way of controlling execution. If you don't want to create separate functions or scripts for them, at least add some command line parameters like "--stop-after-initialization". This way you can rewrite the script without breaking your dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorganize the shell script and create functions.

Seriously, put every line of code into a function.

Then (using ksh as an example), source the script with "." into an interactive shell.

You can now run any of the functions by name, and only the code within that function will run.

The following trivial example illustrates this.  You can use this in two ways:
1) Link the script so you can call it by the name of one of the functions.
2) Source the script (with `. script.sh`) and you can then reuse the functions elsewhere.

```
function one {
     print one
}

function two {
     print two
}

(
    progname=${0##*/}
    case $progname in
    (one|two)
         $progname $@
    esac

)
```

Comment: I've adopted this style for any script longer than 10-12 lines, and it  has made it so much easier to test code and reuse parts of scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own script /tmp/headexecute for example

```
#!/bin/ksh
trap 'rm -f /tmp/somefile' 0
head -n $2 $1 > /tmp/somefile
chmod 755 /tmp/somefile
/tmp/somefile
```

call it with the name of the files and the number of lines to execute

/tmp/headexecute /tmp/originalscript 10

Answer (score 0):

Most shells have no such facility. You will have to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '1{h;d};H;2{x;s/.*/&/ep;q}' script
```

This executes the first two lines of a `script`.

Answer (score 0):

x=*starting line*

y=*number of lines to execute*

eval "$(tail -n +$x script | head -$y)"